# azure webrole remoting not working from home

Tags: azure

[image]Azure webrole --I am not able to remote into my azure webrole from my home .I can remote into the same webrole from my office .But the reasons mentioned in the error message are not correct.,that's why I am able to remote into the same webrole while I am at my office .

I am able to remote into other non-windows-azure machines from my home.But I am getting this error messgae only with my azure Webrole. My machine is Windows8 OS.

Any  workaround for this issue ?

Comment: Downvoting the question... you're asking if there are any workarounds before even figuring out what the issue is. And you haven't provided any sort of details that would help someone to give you advice. For example, you haven't said what the error message is, whether you can remote in to non-Windows-Azure servers, what operating system you're using, what your network setup is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not able to remote into my azure webrole from my home

Could it be that some proxy is preventing you from this? Did you try another network already?

Also take a look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2477176. Could well be that you've exceeded the amount of simultaneous connections.